# How do I go about removing an event handler created in an arrow function so that when the score limit for my game is reached, the buttons stop working

Tags: javascript, event-handling, arrow-functions

Like the title says, I want to have the buttons stop adding score and updating the player/cpu choices on the page. But I can't seem to figure out how to have that happen. Everything I've tried so far doesn't work and the buttons keep on adding score + changing the choices on the page.

I've tried Googling around to find a way to remove the event listener in my endGame() function. But I'm not sure if my syntax is wrong or if there is a different way entirely.

I tried using removeEventListener and I've tried disabling the buttons but that doesn't seem to work. I came across creating handlers to store reference to the function in question, but I have no idea how to apply it to my existing code.
Here is my code as reference.

`````
gameButtons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener("click", () => {
        playerSelection = button.value;

        playGame();
    })
})









`
function compare(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
    if (playerSelection === computerSelection) { 
        
    }
    
    else if (playerSelection === "rock" && computerSelection === "scissors") {
        playerScore++;

        }
    else if (playerSelection === "paper" && computerSelection === "rock") {
        playerScore++;
        
    }
    else if (playerSelection == "scissors" && computerSelection === "paper") {
        playerScore++;

        
    }
    else {
        computerScore++;

    }
    playerScoreText = document.querySelector(".player-score").textContent = `Player score: ${playerScore}`;
    computerScoreText = document.querySelector(".cpu-score").textContent = `CPU score: ${computerScore}`;
    
}

function getComputerChoice() {
    return choice[Math.floor(Math.random() * choice.length)]
}`

function playGame() {
    let playerChoice = document.querySelector(".player-choice").textContent = `Player Chose: ${playerSelection}`
        
    let computerSelection = getComputerChoice();
    let cpuChoice = document.querySelector(".cpu-choice").textContent = `Computer Chose: ${computerSelection}`

    compare(playerSelection, computerSelection);
    endGame();
    
    

    
}

function endGame() {
    if (playerScore === maxScore) {
        console.log("you won")
    }
    else if (computerScore === maxScore) {
        console.log("you lost")
    }
    
}````
`````

Comment: Maybe set a variable to some value that indicates the game is over?

Comment: Disabling the buttons when a condition is met would be better than removing listeners. Maybe you could add your code for that which you can't get working.

Comment: @Andy so I did actually think of that and tried adding that to my endGame() function but I'm not entirely sure how to go about disabling all of the game buttons so that they don't fire off playGame() again.

As in target all the game buttons to have them disabled.

Answer (score 0):

.removeEventListener() needs to be given the same function instance (and the same original value of the `capture` option). Just assign your arrow function to a variable, and then use that variable to remove the listener later.

```
    const buttonListener = () => {
        playerSelection = button.value;

        playGame();
    }

    button.addEventListener("click", buttonListener)

    function endGame() {
        button.removeEventListener("click", buttonListener)

        if (playerScore === maxScore) {
            console.log("you won")
        }
        else if (computerScore === maxScore) {
            console.log("you lost")
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: So I actually realized that the code block was formatted wrong (sorry, first time posting a question)
I have a loop that gives each game button the event listener and that's completely throwing me off.

Comment: No worries, glad you solved it! Also if you mark the answer as accepted that'd be appreciated... I'm trying to get more reputation points so I can post more questions.

Comment: Oh no, I didn't solve it :p

I just wanted to inform you that the code block omitted the part where the loop starts :)